# ExtJs 4 Pie Chart - Re size pie slice

Tags: extjs4

I am using the extjs 4.0.7 pie chart. I want to set the size of a pie slice.

I want this thing because in my charts suppose there are only two slices

1. For January (value = 1000)
2. For February (value = 0.1)

When the chart is rendered for the above data the slice of the February is very small and almost not visible.

I want to increase the size of it and could not figure the way to achieve this.

Can some one help me out to achieve this thing.

Thanks!

Comment: It is obvious that size of slice for February is too small because value for February is very very small. Is your input data correct?

Comment: @Shekhar yes the input data is correct.

Answer (score 0):

`xtype: pie` have property [`lengthField : String`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Pie-cfg-lengthField) where you can set which field name will be used for slice lengths. And value of this field will handle length of each slice. So small values could have big length to see them. Will look like something in [Custom pie demo](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/charts/PieRenderer.html)

---